# Primary and secondary router, wifi speed issue

Tags: wireless-networking, router, speed

I have problem with internet speed.

I connected two routers into network. One as primary, other as secondary by LAN-LAN connection.

Speed on computer in other room, which is 5 meters away is much lower then in my room.

In room where are routers speed is full, 30Mbit/s and upload 3Mbit/s and in second room is just 8Mbit/s after setting Full duplex option as I heard that this gives best speed.

Should I set back to Auto Negotiation?

How to raise speed in other room?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is difficult to understand what you are talking about. Not all computer NICs are the same, so you cannot expect them all to be the same speed. Are all computers connecting via WiFi?

Comment: I have two computers. One in my room and one in living room (laptop). In my room is desktop computer with 2 routers. One primary, one secondary. They are connected wia WAN-WAN connection and they are bridged. On laptop I get wifi signal from that (one merged) network. But speed is slow.